# Spring Handle FlashAttributes after RedirectView

Tags: java, spring

I have a page `check` where I add an `flashAttribute("error","Test message");` and return an `RedirectView` to page `login`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public ModelAndView mainPage(Model model){

    System.out.println(" - " + model.asMap().get("error") + " - "); //-> - null -

    return new ModelAndView("/login");

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/check")
public View checkLogin(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                       @RequestHeader(value = "username", required = false)String username,
                       @RequestHeader(value = "password", required = false)String password){

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Test message");
    return new RedirectView("/login");

}
```

This line: `model.asMap().get("error")` return `null`. How I can handle `RedirectAttributes`?

Comment: The same reason you have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648205/java-spring-session-not-persist-between-requests). Flash attributes are stored in the session, you loose the session somewhere hence no flash attributes. Fix one and it will fix the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward) might help you.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public ModelAndView mainPage(RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs){
    Map<String> attributesMap = redirectAttrs.getFlashAttributes();

    return new ModelAndView("/login");

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/check")
public View checkLogin(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                       @RequestHeader(value = "username", required = false)String username,
                       @RequestHeader(value = "password", required = false)String password){

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Test message");
    return new RedirectView("/login");

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It not works. But I think the problem is at session. How said M. Deinum. Here is my problem with session https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648205/java-spring-session-not-persist-between-requests

Comment: sure, a redirect returns the request to the client with an entity in the http header to request another resourcepath. Because during setting the new request the old request information is deleted, you lose the attributes when not storing it in the model/sessino. I guess this is montioned in the link I've added. Maybe have a look how redirects works on client side.

Comment: I solved my problem with session. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56709797/9011164) if you are interested. But the problem with reading `flashAttribute` still persist. Even with your answer I still don't get value from `flashAttributes`. `redirectAttrs.getFlashAttributes()` is empty even if the session is the same.

Comment: Ok. why do you use RedirectView as a return parameter ? To me it seems you are you want to forward to another resource on the same service. So you can use forward instead of redirect und you can use ModelAndView as return Type.
So maybe try: return new ModelAndView("forward:/login")
maybe have a look here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward
As you can see in point 5 redirect uses a completely new request and forward forwards the same request unchanged.

Comment: I use RedirectView because `redirect:/page` redirect on wrong url. My app run on Tomcat server like `mydom.com/myapp/`. But with Apache as reverse proxy it run directly on `mydom.com/`. When I use `redirect:/page` it redirect to `mydom.com/myapp/page` which is invalid link. RedirectView redirect to `mydom.com/page` which is right. `forward:/page` is a redirect which change page, but url is not changing to `/page`